# Running Multiple Instances of Same Code/Process in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We are fetching data from a web service which takes in mailbox id as input and provides policy id as output, using C# code in SSIS.

The process is as follows:
There is a SQL table containing mailbox id's. The number of mailbox ids for a given execution at a given time may vary (not a constant).
We will provide mailbox id to the web service using C# code in Script task and policy id will be returned. This policy id will be then be inserted into sql table using SQL task.

We want to run this package(which runs the above process) for multiple mailbox id's at the same time.

Any help on designing the package to execute the process in multiple instances would be appreciated.

Comment: You're wanting to ultimately do multiple updates to the same table concurrently?  That sounds risky...

Comment: Are you wanting to run the process in parallel? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We want the SSIS code(package) not just the C# code to run in parallel or multiple instances. These instances should take one input parameter i.e. mail box id.